# Creating SVG rectangles using HSL

Tags: svg

I'm using this to select the color i'm going to paint my rectangle, and with `rgb` its working.

```
style = "fill:rgb(144,0,0)"
```

Now if I try `hsl` no matter which value I set, it will always be black.

```
style = "hsl(28, 87%, 67%)"
```

Whole page code:

```
<svg width='200.000' height='200.00' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<rect x='10.000' y='10.000' width='50.00' height='50.00' style='hsl(28, 87%, 67%)' />
<rect x='70.000' y='10.000' width='50.00' height='50.00' style='hsl(28, 87%, 67%)' />
</svg>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Haskell?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with haskell, as I'm using this program language to create a file to write the svg file.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, it looks like you're just using a Haskell library to put together pieces you built yourself. My guess is maybe you need the `fill:` like you do for RGB.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm so stupid damn... Thank you. It worked !!

Comment: Maybe your comment should be written and answers this prevents that other people invest time to read the question and try to find the error.